# error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: centos, centos5

I am trying to run an application that requires libcurl but I can't start it.

```
 error while loading shared libraries: libcurl.so.4: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I was running centos 5.9 but after update I have now CentOS release 5.11 (Final)

when I run yum install curl i get this:

```
Package curl-7.15.5-17.el5_9.x86_64 already installed and latest version
Package curl-7.15.5-17.el5_9.i386 already installed and latest version
```

when running locate libcurl

```
/usr/lib/libcurl.a
/usr/lib/libcurl.so
/usr/lib/libcurl.so.3
/usr/lib/libcurl.so.3.0.0
/usr/lib/pkgconfig/libcurl.pc
/usr/lib64/libcurl.a
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.3
/usr/lib64/libcurl.so.3.0.0
/usr/lib64/pkgconfig/libcurl.pc
/usr/local/lib64/libcurl.a
/usr/local/lib64/libcurl.so.4
/usr/local/lib64/libcurl.so.4.2.0
/usr/share/man/man3/libcurl-easy.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/libcurl-errors.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/libcurl-multi.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/libcurl-share.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/libcurl-tutorial.3.gz
/usr/share/man/man3/libcurl.3.gz
```

Comment: centos5 is really old. Your application obviously needs newer version of curl. You might get it from some other third-party repository or build it on your own, but updating system to something more recent sounds like a better idea.

Comment: Yes.. I upgraded to centos 6 and works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with `yum whatprovides */libcurl.so.4` and install the packages with matching files. Pay attention to install **both** i386 and x86_64 packages.

If this does not work, please provide the output of the command above.

Answer (score 0):

CentOS 5 is really old. Your application obviously needs newer version of `curl`. You might get it from some other third-party repository or build it on your own, but updating system to something more recent sounds like a better idea.